# "AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse_intermixed_args'"

Tags: python, argparse

I am attempting to develop an application using argparse module in Python3.  I am getting the above error on when attempting to call the function parse._intermixed_args(some_string).

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='string',description='description')
    parser.add_argument('--optional', nargs='+', type=int, help='help text')
    parser.add_argument('name', help='help text')

    if len(commands) > 0:
        args=parser.parse_intermixed_args(commands)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_intermixed_args) `parse_intermixed_args` was introduced in Python 3.7. You must be using an earlier version.

Comment: Thanks I upgraded my pyvenv to version 3.8 and now everything is working fine.